# Failed to create a device file using `uinput` module. Python3 on Ubuntu for Windows

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, keyboard, windows-subsystem-for-linux, uinput

I have a python script that runs on python3.4 and uses the package `keyboard` to allow for keybinds;

```py
keyboard.add_hotkey("enter", self.listener.stop, suppress=True)
keyboard.add_hotkey("shift+enter", self.listener.finish, suppress=True)
```

When I run this on Windows, it works perfectly listening to both hotkeys, also when run on linux (CentOS) it works.

At work I've gotten a Ubuntu environment on my windows via the windows 10 feature and app store. However this environment has a problem with this keyboard hotkey.

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard-0.13.2-py3.6.egg/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py:110: UserWarning: Failed to create a device file using `uinput` module. Sending of events may be limited or unavailable depending on plugged-in devices.
  device = aggregate_devices('kbd')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 32, in <module>
    ], 'test')
  File "/mnt/.../can_controller.py", line 28, in __init__
    self.__initialise_key_handler()
  File "/mnt/.../can_controller.py", line 95, in __initialise_key_handler
    keyboard.add_hotkey("enter", self.listener.stop, suppress=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard-0.13.2-py3.6.egg/keyboard/__init__.py", line 637, in add_hotkey
    _listener.start_if_necessary()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard-0.13.2-py3.6.egg/keyboard/_generic.py", line 35, in start_if_necessary
    self.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard-0.13.2-py3.6.egg/keyboard/__init__.py", line 194, in init
    _os_keyboard.init()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard-0.13.2-py3.6.egg/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 113, in init
    build_device()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard-0.13.2-py3.6.egg/keyboard/_nixkeyboard.py", line 110, in build_device
    device = aggregate_devices('kbd')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keyboard-0.13.2-py3.6.egg/keyboard/_nixcommon.py", line 168, in aggregate_devices
    assert fake_device
AssertionError
```

**If anybody knows how to fix this or has a good work-around. Please let me know.**